# MDADM Configuration

Tags: mdadm

I have two RAID-1 arrays using `mdadm`.  The first Sunday of each month the arrays start running a check (as can be seen in `/proc/mdstat`).  They also seem to stop this check if it has run for some period of time, and resume at some latter time.  I have no problem with doing checks, but I'd like to specify when and for how long between pauses.

Two questions:

1. What are the defaults `mdadm` use for how long to check before pausing, and the pause before starting a new check?
2. How to I override the default/existing configuration for checking the arrays?

I have looked at the [`mdadm.cofig` man page](https://linux.die.net/man/5/mdadm.conf), but I do not see any documentation about this check/timeout.  I am running Linux Mint in case this is a Mint-specific issue.